# Facebook integrates itself on my users' phones violating Content-Security-Policy

Tags: facebook, security, xss, content-security-policy, spyware

I have a site. Site is used by users.
I set the following Content Security Policy:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' data:; 
img-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 
www.google.com www.gstatic.com; connect-src 'self'; frame-src www.google.com; media-src 'self'; 
child-src 'none'; manifest-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe- 
inline' www.gstatic.com www.google.com; report-uri https://my-site.com/policy-report;
```

My site has nothing to do with Facebook. I don't have any integrations with it, such as API/Authentication etc. Zero.

As soon as I deployed this Policy, I started receiving reports about violations.
They're coming from people's mobile devices (iPhones and Andriods)

Here's some of them:

```
[blocked-uri] => https://connect.facebook.net
[violated-directive] => script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.google.com www.gstatic.com


[blockedURI] => https://www.facebook.com/common/scribe_endpoint.php?c=iab_autofill_js_detection&....(and many more url parameters)
[violatedDirective] => img-src


[blockedURI] => https://www.facebook.com/common/scribe_endpoint.php?c=iab_autofill_js_event&m=%7B%22event%22%3A%22FIRST_FORM_INTERACTION%22%7D
[violatedDirective] => img-src
```

Can anyone please shed some light on this?
The question is what is Facebook doing in people's phone's browsers on my site?
Is it some kind of browser extension (data mining spyware) that affects every site user visits? If yes, which one?

The reason I need to know is I want to test this behavior myself, to make sure my users don't see any weird blocked Facebook's content on my site.

Thank you

Comment: It's look like a [Facebook pixel](https://en-gb.facebook.com/business/help/742478679120153?id=1205376682832142), just open Url https://www.facebook.com/common/scribe_endpoint.php?c=iab_autofill_js_event&m=%7B%22event%22%3A%22FIRST_FORM_INTERACTION%22%7D and have a look. Facebook likes to track users.

Comment: I’m guessing that probably happens in the in-app browser (IAB), that is used by default when people open an external link from within the native mobile Facebook app. That is a webview component integrated into the app, so they can probably interfere with the loaded content however they like. To verify, try and match one of your policy violation reports, to the user agent recorded in your access log, by exact timestamp.

Comment: https://blog.tomayac.com/2019/12/09/inspecting-facebooks-webview/ _“On top of limited features, WebViews can also be used for effectively conducting intended man-in-the-middle attacks, since the IAB developer can arbitrarily inject JavaScript code and also intercept network traffic.”_ According to that site, you can also remote-debug the Facebook IAB webview now, that could also be a way to get some more insight into what exactly the inject.